# Prove that formula equals to the triangle's area

Tags: geometry, area

[image]

We need to prove that right triangles area equals to $AK \times KB$, first i tried to draw lines where sides touch circle and got formula $S = r^2 + AK\times r + KB\times r$, but it leads to nowhere. can anyone give me hint about this problem?

Comment: that's difficult without any idea about what you know already. Which formulae for the area are you aware of? Do you know the standard relationships for right triangles? Like Pythagoras, and $ab = h_c^2, ab= h_cc, a^2 = cp, b^2 = cq$?

Comment: @Thomas i know first two ones, what is p and q? I know bh/2 formula

Comment: @NikoMolecule: Note that
$$r^2 + AK\cdot r+BK\cdot r \;=\; (r+AK)(r+BK) - AK\cdot BK$$
You have observed that the left-hand side gives the area. What can you say about the first term on the right-hand side? And then what does that say about the last term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

$AK=AD, BK=BE$ (tangents from same point)
$CD=CE=OD=OE=r$ (radius)

$2S=AC\times BC= (AK+r)(BK+r)=AK\times BK + AK\times r+ BK\times r+r^2...I$ (double the area of triangle)

$2S-AK\times BK=AK\times r+ BK\times r+r^2$

$(AK+BK)^2=(AK+r)^2+(BK+r)^2$ (pyhta)

$AK^2+BK^2+2\times AK\times BK=AK^2+r^2+2\times AK\times r + BK^2+r^2+2\times BK\times r$

$2\times AK\times BK=r^2+2\times AK\times r + r^2+2\times BK\times r$

$AK\times BK=r^2+ AK\times r + r^2+BK\times r ...II$

then from $I\& II$

$2S-AK\times BK=AK\times BK$

$S=AK\times BK$